# Three way relationship model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working on a small movie database as a personal project. 
At first, I went with what I think is pretty standard as far as movie databases go when it comes to dealing with actors/directors/writers: Two main entities "Movie" and "People" with a bunch of M2M association tables, such as "Movie to director", "Movie to actor", "Movie to writer"...

It soon seemed like a better choice was possible. I mean, there are plenty of positions in movies, cinematographer, assistant producer, cgi artist, etc. Having a separate association table for each job seems counterproductive.

My first idea then was to have a single association table, "Movie to people", with an extra field/column "Role". But I'm not sure if it's standard/acceptable/efficient to have a custom field like that in an association table.

My last idea was to configure a third main entity, "Profession", that stores all of the jobs possible in a movie: actor, director, writer, etc. The three main entity "Movie", "People" and "Profession" can then be linked together with a single three way association table. With this association table, I can have "John" in "Movie X" as "actor", or "Mary" in "Movie Z" as "actor".

So far my tables are like this (I simplified the code a little, for clarity):

```
class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movie'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    year = Column(Integer)
    ## country and genre with m2m relationship
    country = relationship('Country', secondary='movie_x_country', backref='movie')
    genre = relationship('Genre', secondary='movie_x_genre', backref='movie')

class People(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64), index=True)

class Profession(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'profession'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    profession = Column(String(64), index=True, unique=True)
```

And the association table:

```
class Movie_x_People(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movie_x_people'
    movie_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('movie.id'))
    people_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('people.id'))
    profession_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('profession.id'))
```

So yeah, first, I'd like to know if this is ok to do? I have a very limited experience with sql, but I haven't seen this kind of setup. For what I see, the main problem is that i could make queries a bit difficult, but sqlalchemy can maybe do its magic?

My first roadblock, and the reason why I post, is that I want to add a couple of fields to my "Movie" class, so I can add actors and directors easily (other jobs can be handled differently, I guess).

```
class Movie(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'movie'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    year = Column(Integer)
    ## country and genre with m2m relationship
    country = relationship('Country', secondary='movie_x_country', backref='movie')
    genre = relationship('Genre', secondary='movie_x_genre', backref='movie')
    # director = ??**
    # actor = ?? **
```

I did some tests, but I can't really get my head around it. And since I'm pretty new to both sql and sqlalchemy, I'm really stuck. Been stuck for two days on this.

It should go something like:

```
director = relationship('People', secondary='movie_x_people',                  primaryjoin="and_(people.profession.profession=='director')")
```

But that's not quite right, it's missing something haha

As I am here, I can also ask a secondary question: where could I add information about the character's name (role name) for actors in movie? I can't really find room, unless I add a primary key "id" to my "movie x people" table and do a One to One relation?

Comment: Generally, when I encounter design problems like this, I don't do it in Python. I don't even do it in SQL. I do it in spreadsheets. That said, what I'm thinking here is that you need more than just 3-4 tables. Highly suggest you scour a movie database like IMDB and try to figure out how they're doing what they're doing in their site.

Personally, what I'd do is check up to what level of _normalization_ I am comfortable with. You can read a good overview [here](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/).

Comment: Can you elaborate, what do you mean by doing it on spreadsheet? I've turn the problem around with paper and pen, and tried to draw how tables can relate to each others.

As for looking at other models, most models I can find are either pretty simple but always have separate tables for directors and actors (and probably ignore other jobs), or are very complicated.
https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/ didn't help me, I can't understand how they link the different tables together, especially how the "cast" table is used.